# Problem in connection fhirbase to postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, hl7-fhir

In am trying to connect my fhirbase database schema with my postgrest database and it gives me following error.

```
fhirbase --host localhost -p 5432 -d fhirbase -U postgres -W root --fhir=3.3.0 init
2023/08/04 15:47:52 Error connecting to database: unknown authentication type: 10
```

What could be the reason?

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 15.3 (Ubuntu 15.3-1.pgdg20.04+1)
```

Here is the version of psql.

I couldn't find the reason why its not working?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.